# Bare minimum Owin OAuth external login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, owin

I'm trying to implement google external login using owin, I don't need to save the user in Db, all the demos that I've found are tied to EntityFramework, so I tried to strip it down and got to a working implementation here it is:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication("myid00000000000.apps.googleusercontent.com", "mysecret");
    }
}
```

and the controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return Content("failed");
        }

        return Content("logged in");
    }

internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult 
...
```

now I don't know for sure if this is enough, if I haven't missed some user validation steps,
when I call `Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` and I get a non null result does that mean that I can be sure that the info in `loginInfo` is actually coming from google or do I need to do some additional requests to google to check this info ?

Comment: No, you should be fine with what you have. But, if you don't trust it, debug and inspect everything that's happening, so you can verify for yourself that it's working.

Comment: @ChrisPratt when I debug it loginInfo has the profile Info name, email, coming from google, it's just my first time experimenting with this and I thought that I need to validate this info, guess owin already did it

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you stored the output of Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() in a variable "loginInfo"

Now, check the value of loginInfo.Result.Login.LoginProvider. If the value is "Google", then the info you received was from Google.